# How to change CSS attributes of an element with JS when element is pulled from a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can't figure out how to change the CSS attributes of this object.

```
$(".slots").html('').get(0)
```

I am just playing around and this is how I get some data for my JS, perhaps am I doing this wrong? But question still remains the same - how do I alter that elements CSS attributes?

Comment: Try this : $(".slots").html('').get(0).css("color", "#fff");

Comment: I tried before, kept saying that CSS is not a function. Hence I'm here.

Comment: Try: $(".slots").get(0).html('').css("color", "#ff0000");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues was that the code was not wrapped in $() to create the correct reference to the element. Below fixed the issue

﻿

```
$($(".slots").html('').get(0)).css("background-color","blue")
```